# how to authenticate logins in python tkinter?

Tags: python

hi I want to check the exact password for a particular username in a database,what can I do

```
def login():
     conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
     cur = conn.cursor()
     un = E_Username.get()
     pw = E_Password.get()
     cur.execute("SELECT username,password FROM users") 
     # build a set with all names, from the results given as [('name1',), ('name2',), ('name3',)]
     names = {username[0] for username in cur.fetchall()}
     key = {password[0] for password in cur.fetchall()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use WHERE statement to fetch password from database

```
cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=?", (un,))
```